# Two methods of trig substitution for the integral of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-25}}{x}$

Tags: calculus

I used two different geometric constructions to solve the problem seen below with trig substitution, and I can't quite understand why I'm getting two differing yet similar results. The first time I oriented the triangle with $\sqrt{x^2-25}$ as the base. The second time I oriented the right triangle with $\sqrt{x^2-25}$ as the height. Why would this produce different answers if the substitution that occurs is still mathematically correct?
[See image attatched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4c4j.jpg)

Comment: $\theta$ means something different in either method. What happens if you replace $\theta$ to get the antiderivative back in terms of $x$?

Comment: The angle taken in case $1$ is complimentary with the one taken in the second case. Recall that $\tan(\pi/2-\theta)=\cot(\theta)$

Comment: There are different $\theta$ in both. Rewrite these in terms of $x.$

Comment: The left side becomes sqrt(x^2-25) + 5(csc^-1(x/5)) + C when taken in terms of x. The right side meanwhile becomes sqrt(x^2-25) - 5(sec^-1(x/5)) + C. I apologize for the formatting I'm just starting to learn Latex.